# What should the Slug look like for an IP address in CIDR notation? (e.g. 10.10.10.77/28)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, slug

An ASP.NET MVC app needs to display this URL `http://host.com/IPAddress/10.10.10.77/28`  ; however the periods `.` and forward slashes `/` conflict with ASP.NET MVC.

How should I handle this request?  Some approaches I thought of include:

- Replace the problem strings with "magic" strings such as 10-10-10--28, then convert that back to the logical value
- Preface the value with the Key, so the value is just a slug:
  `http://host.com/IPAddress/27/10-10-10--28`

  Looking at the entry above I lose ability to key directly off an IP address and it still doesn't look right
- Configure ASP.NET to ignore periods (somehow) and ignore the last slash (perhaps by routing)
  `http://host.com/IPAddress/10.10.10.77/28`

I haven't thought much about IPv6, but I suppose I need to include plans for that as well.  How do you think I should approach this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't URL-encode that part of the string?

Comment: @Joe The customer likes the idea of typing in the ipaddress directly into the URL.  URL encoding gets "too messy", and not functional for her target end users

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't that it conflicts with MVC, it's that it doesn't match the default route syntax.  To create a route to match this syntax I believe the best route is to use a RegEx-based route.  This is one I've used before: http://www.iridescence.no/Posts/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx.  You will need an expression for both v4 and v6 addresses.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with the generation of outbound links. http://www.iridescence.no/post/Outbound-Urls-with-Regular-Expression-Routes.aspx   I'll keep this open in hopes of a better solution that I can't locate

Comment: Yes this is a limitation of the regex route (unless you add the virtual path creation part) because a RegEx matches incoming values but does not generate outbound values to match the string.